# Stuck on Mean word length

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, mean

The goal of this code was to create a program using main method java to analysis a piece text which has been entered from a user.

They do this by entering the text into a scanner which is then analysed by the program. The analysis is to produce word frequency, for example " This is a test" produces this results:

```
This is a test
1 letter words: 1
2 letter words: 1
3 letter words: 0
4 letter words: 2
5 letter words: 0
```

The bit that I'm stuck on is producing a mean/average, My guts telling to divide
`counts.length` by `str.length` but I'm not the Best at java and I've tried to implement this but all I get are errors. I'm not expecting anyone to just hand me code, but if someone could give me a hint in what I should do or just point me the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Text_AD { 

    public static void main (String[] args) {

while(true){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter text: "); 
    String s;
    s = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("" + s);

    String[] strings = s.split(" ");
    int[] counts = new int[6];
    for(String str : strings)
        if(str.length() < counts.length) counts[str.length()] += 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++)

        System.out.println(i + " letter words: " + counts[i]);  


    }}}
```

Comment: how are the input words are seperated? are they seperated by " "(space). could it have "." or "," and etc?

Comment: @nafas it seems they are separated by spaces, according to `String[] strings = s.split(" ");`

Comment: one more thing? what do you mean by average?

Comment: The Words are seprated by a single space " "

Comment: @jaytj95 - *slight* correction.. The OP is *assuming* that they are seperated by a *single space.*

Comment: @TheLostMind this is true, but OP's method only accounts for single spaces, so any other character would be considered a "letter"

Comment: @jaytj95 - yes.. that's right..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By average, I am assuming that you mean the **mean** length. I am also assuming you want to get a floating point **mean**. In which case you just need to divide the total of all the lengths in `strings` by the length of the array itself.

You could do something like the following;

```
int total = 0;
for(String s : strings) total += s.length();
System.out.println((double)total/strings.length);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you are not calculating the times how often a string was present (if that was needed as well)

Comment: @Seega - Shouldn't make any difference. We're just looping through all the words in the line. Whether they are a double of an already existing word is irrelevant. They didn't ask for the mean length of words excluding duplicates.

Comment: Oh I thought you are looping through the counts array. My fault. You are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Without breaking up your code much, you could run a `for` loop through your `counts[]` array, adding up all the values, and then dividing by `counts.length` to get the average.

Be aware of type casting though. You may want to do Double division instead of integer.

Comment: And what would that fix?

Comment: @TheLostMind I'm assuming he wants the mean number of letters?

Answer (score 0):

It this what you are looking for?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class While_Loop { 

public static void main (String[] args) {

    int lengthSum, wordCount;
    lengthSum = wordCount = 0;

    while(true){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter text: "); 
    String s;
    s = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("" + s);

    String[] strings = s.split(" ");
    int[] counts = new int[6];
    for(String str : strings)
        if(str.length() < counts.length) counts[str.length()] += 1;
        wordCount++;
        lengthSum += str.length();
    for(int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++)

        System.out.println(i + " letter words: " + counts[i]);  

    System.out.println("Average: " + lengthSum/wordCount);

  }}}
```

**NOTE:** I only added stuff to your code.  The way it is written is pretty messy.  I'd clean up some of the for loops and the brackets at the end for practice making the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

When I understand you correct you should have one variable `int totalCount = 0;` where you add 
`totalCount += i*counts[i];` in your last for loop.

After the loop you can simply divide through the size-1 (because 0 does not count)

`double average = totalCount/(counts.length-1);`

**Alternative way**

You take the inputstring length without the spaces and divide it by the number of spaces + 1 (which is equal to the number of words)

Comment: Using `counts.length-1` gets you one less than the number of words in the array. Also, talking about the number of spaces; there could be spaces before and after the line which would invalidate your results.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();


        System.out.println("Enter text: ");
        String s = "This is a sample text";
        System.out.println("" + s);

        String[] strings = s.split(" ");

        for(String str : strings) {                                                
            Integer counter = map.get(str.length())==null?0:map.get(str.length());
            map.put(str.length(),counter++);                
        }

        Integer sum=0;
        Integer counter=0;
        for(Integer len : map.keySet()) {
            sum+=len*map.get(len);
            counter+=map.get(len);
        }
        Double average = Double.valueOf(sum/counter);
```

Or you can combine the loops

Answer (score -1):

Few suggestions which might help you (not related to the specific question).

1. Choose a meaningful class name rather than `While_Loop` .
2. Do, `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` before the start of the loop.
3. As soon as you read each line, do the following.
4. Split the line using `"\\s+"` .
5. Create a HashMap with Key as Count (Integer) and Value as a list of Words with that count. Create this *outside the loop*.
6. *For each* split word,,get the length . and check if the map already *contains* the count, get the list (value), add he current word to it. else, add a new entry with the word as the single entry in the list.
7. Get the `keySet` of the map, add values of all keys i.e, *count * number of elements in the list*. then divide by total number of elements.
8. And yes, I know this is a *very big* change (something you might as well ignore..). But this is the right way to go.

Comment: A bit complex right now for me, Only just started to learn java over the summer. But thanks for the advice and the edit.

Comment: @Alice - There is never a bad time to start. :P.. anyways.. you are welcome.. BTW do implement the *second* point (major performance impact)..